# Good links/books about JavaScript event handlers

Tags: javascript, events

I have been playing around JavaScript for a year or so, one thing I learned is that event handling has to be done very carefully so now I would like to learn JavaScript event handling very seriously.

One of the reason to be so serious is that I would like to try hands on some small game in JavaScript using Canvas and I would like to polish, correct and get right my concepts.

Can some one help/guide me to books/links where I can get to know/understand good parts/practices/understanding of JavaScript event handling that would help to be Pro in JavaScript (Pro ? not sure which term can describe it well, but hope it helped).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html) and Jan Wolters (about [Key Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) and [Mouse Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html)) provide good descriptions of event handler.

Above all, I'd recommend reading a good book on JavaScript, e.g. David Flanagan's [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101996).